# WooCommerce: Different "shop base address" for different products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency, tax

In our project, we have a specific scenario. Basically, we need to set calculation of tax based on:

**Shop base address**

but that address should be different for each product.

Product A = Address A
Product B = address B

So taxes and currency are then set based on selected product address.

Please does anyone have idea/experience if it is possible in WooCommerce settings somewhere, or it would need plugin/custom PHP code?

Thanks,
J.

Comment: Image is missing.

Comment: Yes, sorry, stack overflow didn't let me upload, beacuse I have not enough of reputation. I have uploaded it here: https://app.box.com/s/m0xluhmujyajpzl3o6nkemvnhxhfpklv.